# How to stop a div from scrolling past header when using position; sticky?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header that uses `position: sticky;` to stick to the page before the top. This leaves a gap between the header and the top of the page. If you scroll, you can see the content div going under and past the header. I could put `top: 0;` to hide the scrolling, but the gap was intentional. How could this be fixed so that the scrolled content disappears before going past the header?

I've tried using overflow, but then the scrollbar appears inside of the div itself, where as I want to be able to scroll anywhere on the page. When zooming in on the page, 2 scrollbars appear instead of just 1. Also since the header border corners are rounded, when using overflow the content div stops at the same point as the header and the hard edges of the content div would appear below the rounded corners.

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 6px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 40px;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
  border-left: 6px solid black;
  border-right: 6px solid black;
}

#footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 6px solid black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want `header` to be at top? so you can just set `top:0;`,what you are saying that can be done using javascript but in real life, when we build projects, we don't do these kinds of things.

Comment: No, the gap was intentional.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this:

```
position: fixed;
```

Add this to the div and see if it works.